# Excel vba: object variable or with block variable not set, getting class collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `Client` class that contains a `losses Collection`. I use that collection later in a program, retrieving its elements. However, now I get the `object variable or with block variable not set` error, when trying to retrieve an element (after minor changes in code):

These are the insides of a `Client` class:

```
Public Property Let setSumLosses(value As Collection)
    Set sumLosses = value
End Property


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sumLosses = New Collection
End Sub

Private losses As Collection
Private sumLosses As Collection

Public Property Get getLosses()
    Set getLosses = losses
End Property
```

This function is used in a main sub:

```
Function calculateSumLosses(clientsColl As Collection)
    Dim clientCopy As client

    For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
         MsgBox ("here: " & clientCopy.getLosses.Item(simulation)) 'msgBoxes fine

         ...
    Next

    ...
End Function
```

**EDIT:**
The `calculateLosses` function, inside `Client` class:

```
Public Sub calculateLosses()
    Set losses = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To outcomes.Count
        If outcomes(i) = 1 Then
            losses.Add totalLoss
        ElseIf outcomes(i) = 0 Then
            losses.Add 0
        Else
            losses.Add Null
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The main sub:

```
clientCopy.calculateLosses        
clientCopy.setSumLosses = calculateSumLosses(clientsDividedColl)
```

The thing is, while the error appears on `MsgBox` line, the "here" part and the element itself still get printed out fine and only after I click "OK" on `MsgBox` the error on that line appears. What could possible cause it?

Comment: you never initialize the collection losses. you need `set losses = New Collection`

Comment: @Sorceri I'm sorry, I do. It doesn't occur in `Private Sub Class_Initialize()`, but in `calculateLosses`. Edited the question.

Comment: @Ans So it sounds like the loop runs once through fine, but it's on the next iteration that your error occurs? What is the value of `simulation`? Where does that come from?

Comment: There's not enough information for  me to reproduce the problem. If no one else can help, I suggest you read Help for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question appropriately.  Best would be if you could upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) that reproduces the problem, and post a link here.

Comment: Set your VBA error handling option (Tools>>Options>>General) to "Break in Class Module" and see if the error is in your class.